# Speed up a query using ST_Within and ST_PointOnSurface

Tags: postgis, performance

```sql
CREATE TABLE municipal_area (
    id varchar NOT NULL,
    "name" varchar NOT NULL,
    state_id varchar NOT NULL,
    state_abbr varchar NOT NULL,
    state_name varchar NOT NULL,
    country_code varchar NOT NULL,
    country_name varchar NOT NULL,
    geom public.geometry(geometry, 4326) NOT NULL, -- these are usually multi-polygons
    CONSTRAINT pk_county PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_municipal_area_id_country_code ON municipal_area USING btree (id, country_code DESC);
CREATE INDEX municipal_area_geom_idx ON municipal_area USING gist (geom);
```

Given a geom X I need to find with `municipal_area` the geom falls inside.

```sql
SELECT
        ma.id AS county_id,
        ma.country_code as country,
        ma.state_abbr as "state",
        ma."name" as municipal_area,
        ST_Extent($geom) as extent,
        ST_Area($geom::geography) as area_sq_m,
        ST_IsValid($geom) as is_valid,
        ST_MakeValid($geom) as valid_geom
    FROM municipal_area ma
    WHERE ST_Within(ST_PointOnSurface($geom), ma.geom::geometry) IS TRUE
    -- WHERE ST_Covers(ma.geom::geometry, ST_PointOnSurface($geom)) IS TRUE
    GROUP BY ma.id, ma.country_code, ma.state_abbr, ma."name"
```

This should always return one row or none. The `municipal_area` table has about 7500 rows and will not have more.

The exec plan:

```
Node Type   Entity  Cost    Rows    Time    Condition
Aggregate   [NULL]  110174.77 - 110175.04   1   77.283  [NULL]
Sort    [NULL]  110174.77 - 110174.77   1   77.263  [NULL]
Gather  [NULL]  1000.00 - 110174.76 1   77.253  [NULL]
Parallel Seq Scan   municipal_area  0.00 - 109174.66    0   56.195  "(
    st_within(
        'redacted'::geometry
        , (ma.geom)::geometry
    ) IS TRUE
)"
```

I have an index on the geom in `municipal_area`. I tried using `ST_Covers` and the difference was within a MOE so either one works, no clear winner there.

Is there anything I can do to improve the performance of that query? My first stab at it would be to add an extent geom for all the muni areas and then use the extent as part of the select (hopefully the query planner can sort out that finding which box the point sits inside of is easier than finding out which multipolygon the point sits inside of?).

Comment: If you use `ST_Intersects` what is the performance like?

Comment: Maybe it was the older build of PG (9.4), but I found I often had to `and` what should have been an implicit `geom1 && geom2` to coax performance out of a `ST_Within(ST_PointOnSurface(geom1),geom2)`. YMMV.

Comment: Is this some theoretical exercise? When you create the PointOnSurface you know already for which municipal_area geometry it is computed. Why to query "create the PointOnSurface for municipality 'my_home_town' and check within which municipality the point is"?

Comment: so the total time is 77ms right? There is little room for improvement.

Comment: You have mentioned multipolygons, which can be unfriendly with the spatial index (one bbox for each entire multipolygon). Also if the polygons have many vertices, checking if a point is inside or not can be very expensive. In such cases, it can help a lot to subdivide the polygons into lots of small ones. http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2019/11/subdivide.html

Comment: "When you create the PointOnSurface you know already for which municipal_area geometry it is computed." no, the point is within a polygon and that point MAY be within ONE of the polygons in the table

Comment: @jgh what about the idea of calculating the extent of all the muni areas up front and then finding which extent the point resides within?

Comment: The planner choses a `parallel seq scan` here - a multi-threaded direct I/O scan of physical rows - instead of loading the index in memory and the subsequent random disk access to fetch the respective rows to check against; index usage does not come for free, and is often less performant for small amounts of indexed rows. As @JGH suggests, and to both make some use of the index as well as reduce geometric operations during the actual check, `ST_Subdivide` your `municipal_area`s. Always use `ST_Intersects` for plain PIP queries. Do not `GROUP BY` if you don't aggregate (maybe use `ST_Envelope`)

Comment: I have to use grouping if I use `ST_Extent` and it is required for the results we need. I don't understand why I'd use `ST_Intersects` to find out if a point is within a polygon when `ST_Within` seems more built to that purpose (and I have to assume would be faster for it).

Comment: @Vince what's this "title as statement" about? Is that some community standard? Never heard of it.

Comment: Be aware that `ST_Within/ST_Contains` have the ["polygons do not contain their boundary"](https://lin-ear-th-inking.blogspot.com/2007/06/subtleties-of-ogc-covers-spatial.html) quirk.   You could use `ST_CoveredBy` - but `ST_Intersects` has the same semantics for point/polygon, and tends to be more optimized in general.

Comment: I ran it with all three (`ST_Within`,`ST_Intersects` and `ST_Covers`) and the average of 10 queries was 84, 95 and 146 ms respectively. `ST_Within` is the clear choice.

Comment: The `ST_Extent` of a single `GEOMETRY` is its `ST_Envelope` (or the `Box2D(ST_Envelope)` if a `BOX2D` is what you need) - no need for aggregation. As @dr_jts hints at, If a point happens to be on the border of a polygon it is not `ST_Within`; depending on the tendency for axis alignment and precision the chances are anywhere between unbievably low, and moderate. Without the *relatively* costly geometry processing of that input geometry in your query a simple id + geom lookup could very well stay below 10ms, if the vertex counts are low enough as well (sth. like <500).

Comment: Since an index lookup is your best chance for a performant boost, try `VACUUM ANALYZE municipal_area;` and rerun, or check against a run with `SET enable_seqscan=false;` if that didn't help, just to see if an index lookup would make a difference. There are other means to hint the planner towards index usage if your tests show it helps, like the explicitly additional `&&` bbox comparison @Vince mentioned or, lastly, subdividing into many more rows of smaller geometries (less computations) witjh better index efficiency over less overlapping bboxes - which may or may not help with this query.

Comment: BTW. the idea of checking if the point is within the extent of a polygon is the core of the `GIST(geom)` indexation - if you are only interested in that condition you will want to simply use `... WHERE geom && <input_point>;`. Obviously, if there are overlapping extents there can be as many hits.